# Applying the L'Hospital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let
$$f(t)=(c-1)t^3,$$
$$g(t)=\displaystyle\int _{\sqrt{\pi}}^{t}\left(\sin{(u^2)}-cu^2\right)du,$$
$h(t)=\dfrac{f(t)}{g(t)}$  ($c$ is a constant)

Now, let's assume that $c$ satisfies $g(0)=0$. Is it right to say that when we solve $$\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} h(t), \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f^{\prime}(t)}{g ^{\prime}(t)} = \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{3(c-1)t^2}{\sin{(t^2)} - ct^2} = \dfrac{3(c-1)}{1-c} = -3$$

?

Furthermore, is there a workaround WITHOUT using the L'Hospital's rule? I tried the following approach but does not work.

$$\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0} \cfrac{\cfrac{f(t) - f(0) }{t}}{\cfrac{g(t) - g(0)}{t}} = \dfrac{f^{\prime}(0)}{g^{\prime}(0)}=\dfrac{0}{0}$$

Comment: the first approach seems fine. It will be tricky without using L'Hopital's

Comment: Your choice of $c$, expressible in terms of the [Fresnel $S$-integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral), doesn't give that value of $\frac{3(c-1)}{1-c}$ (in fact, no finite $c$ does).

Comment: On the assumption that $c$ satisfies $g(0)=0,$ you can indeed conclude that $\lim_{t\to 0}{h(t)}=-3,$ since then $\lim_{t\to 0}{g(t)}=0,$ by continuity, and then you could apply Lhopital. Which other method would you seek? Any such method would be equivalent to Lhopital, in any case.